# How can I calculate the gradient of a vector field from its values?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vector, gradient, derivative

I'd like some help with numpy and arrays. I want to calculate the gradient of a vector field.

Suppose I have a function foo that takes a tuple of coordinates (x,y,z) and returns a vector (u,v,w).

Then if I have an array of coordinates POS = [[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],[x3,y3,z3],etc] I can generate an array of vectors with origin in pos and direction in DIR = [[u1,v1,w1],[u2,v2,w2],[u3,v3,w3],etc].

Now how could I calculate the gradient of this vector field in every point of POS ? What I need in the end would be something like another array GRAD = [grad1, grad2, grad3, etc] where every grad would be a 3x3 array of the partial derivatives of the vector field in that corresponding point in POS.

PS: I know I can derivate manually the function foo and then implement the derivatives in python but in my case the function foo is really complex and I want to do the derivatives this way :)

EDIT1: for now I'm coming up with POS this way:

```
parts = 100
limit = 10
xs = linspace(-limit, limit, parts)
ys = linspace(-limit, limit, parts)
zs = linspace(-limit, limit, parts)

POS = array([(x, y, z) for z in zs for y in ys for x in xs])
DIR = array([foo(pos) for pos in POS])
```

which allows me to do this if necessary:

```
POS = POS.reshape(parts,parts,parts,3)
DIR = DIR.reshape(parts,parts,parts,3)
```

Comment: If my answer answers the question please consider accepting it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.gradient` for this in the following way:

```
import numpy as np

N = 100
limit = .1

def vec(x,y,z): # Example vector field
    return np.array([x,x,z])

x = np.arange(-limit, limit, 2*limit/N) # np.arange takes the spacing as 3. arg
y = np.arange(-limit, limit, 2*limit/N)
z = np.arange(-limit, limit, 2*limit/N)

# Create 3D grid from 1D arrays, indexing is important!
X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z,indexing='ij') 
V = vec(X,Y,Z) # Get vector field, shape: (3,N,N,N)

D = np.gradient(V, x, y, z, axis=(1,2,3)) # Get gradient, this is a list!
D = np.array(D).transpose((1,0,2,3,4)) # Make it an array and flip first axes.
```

The resulting array has shape `(3,3,N,N,N)` where the first axis indexes the component of the vector field and the second axis indexes the coordinate direction w.r.t. which the derivative was computed.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks a lot! Just to make sure I got the shapes, in the end D[i, j, :, :, :] would return the dij from the jacobian matrix of each point of the grid? Like D[0,0,:,:,:] would return all dU/dx and D[1,1,:,:,:] all the dV/dy.

Comment: Yes, to be sure: D[0,1,:,:,:] gives all dU/dy.

Comment: @DavidWierichs What if the grid is arbitrary/irregular?

Comment: That is why we pass the positions to `np.gradient` (note that they are the 1D arrays per coordinate `x, y, z`, not the meshgrid coordinates `X, Y, Z`). They only have to match in shape, but can be arbitrarily spaced. (for the application above, it actually would have been best to specify a single spacing value `2 *limit/N`, which then is used for all 3 directions and all spacings in each of the directions.)